# device/rig to establish ground truth data about car parameters

Tags: sensor

We are looking to conduct research into automotive technology and were wondering if there exists some device/rig that can help in measuring vehicle parameters to establish ground truth. We would like to outfit a couple of vehicles with these sensors like that could give us accurate measures of distance, speed, fuel level, fuel consumption, etc.

Eg. wheel encoders could give us distance and speed.

Where can I get more information about this? How do the car manufacturers do this testing? Would we have to approach the manufacturers themselves to get the data?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Even if the manufacturers have this data - WHY on earth would they give it to you?

Comment: Can you just tap into the CAN bus and read the data directly from there?

Comment: Pick up a WIFI / Bluetooth reader ( or even a USB cable version) then port that directly to your laptop for data recording.